# Issue with code coverage in get & set methods in apex

Tags: apex, code-coverage

The problem while covering the code is that the get method is not covering, while the set method covers.

Example, below code covers (that's in blue):

```
public void setselectedPlanRouteId(string SelectedPlanRouteId)
{
    this.selectedPlanRouteId = SelectedPlanRouteId;
}
```

And the below of this line doesn't (that's in red):

```
public String getselectedPlanRouteId()
{
    return this.selectedPlanRouteId;
}
```

What goes wrong that it does not cover the code? Thanks

Comment: nothing. it depends on your functionality if you want to cover these lines or not. but as a best practices if your line is not covered in test class then you should check if you actually need those lines.

Comment: @TusharSharma Thanks. I deleted the piece of code that not usable and guess what % raised. Thanks again.

Comment: @TusharSharma reputation below 15. though accepted the ans. thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing. it depends on your functionality if you want to cover these lines or not. but as a best practices if your line is not covered in test class then you should check if you actually need those lines.

Or another solution you can try what @croperdy suggest. Use assert to validate.

Comment: I did comment few of the properties which isn't useful anywhere further. Working fine. Also I took care of try and catch, both. Did negative testing and the overall coverage got increased significantly, which i didn't earlier. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could write the above logic in a more compact fashion

```
public selectedPlanRouteId {get; set;}
```

and test coverage is obtained by (assuming `ctlr` is a reference to the controller object)

```
ctlr.selectedPlanRouteId = 'foo';  // tests setter
system.assertEquals('foo',ctlr.selectedPlanRouteId);  // tests getter
```

Comment: I do agree about the compact fashion thing.

Answer (score 0):

call like a normal method. it cover the code

```
classname cn = new classname();

cn.getselectedPlanRouteId();

cn.setselectedPlanRouteId('pass string value');
```